# Open SSRS with VS2008 BIDS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, bids

I've installed a new instance of Visual Studio 2008 BIDS on my laptop ([from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842)) and I am trying to open an existing 2008 reports solution. It opens, however all the shared datasets appear to be missing and when I try to build I get the following error:

```
[rsInvalidReportDefinition] The report definition is not valid. 
 Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace
          'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' 
          which cannot be upgraded.
```

I've tried installing the Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package referred to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727561/345659), but nothing changed.
I've also tried just updating the xml to 2008 as the reverse of what is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244201/345659) with no success.

My best guess is that maybe my laptop is missing some kind of file? But Windows Updates are up to date.

The reports solution opens fine on another PC with Visual Studio 2008 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10587329/345659) says that SQL Server 2008 does not support shared datasets, only 2008 R2.

So I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and got a different error:

```
The dataset, MyDataset, is a shared dataset. 
SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services does not support shared data sets.
```

Which according to [this msdn forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/08ccb387-ca7f-4a3d-9f77-e6f9d95f105f/does-sql-server-2008-r2-express-reporting-service-support-shared-datasets?forum=sqlreportingservices) describes that the Express version does not support shared datasets.

> Shared Dataset is tied with “Report Part Gallery” in terms of SKU restrictions. As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365156.aspx), Report Part Gallery is only available in Standard Edition and above.

---

Upgrading to the Standard version of SQL Server 2008 R2 fixed the problem.
(Maintenance > Edition Upgrade in the setup)

I also had to change my project properties > TargetServerVersion from `SQL Server 2008` back to `SQL Server 2008 R2`, which had been automatically changed in the project file when I opened it without having R2 installed.